# How to avoid files in use while deleting

Tags: windows-10

An upgrade to Windows 10 left a user with a scheduled task that repeatedly copied the same files in unique named sub directories in the Temp directory. It has reached 200GB and filled the C drive.

When we try to delete in Windows it drops out, usually when it comes across a file in use. DOS del /Q /F /S . dropped out immediately with a file in use error. Can we delete recursively while avoiding files in use?

Edit: The task has been deleted. We want to delete the mess without having to close the programs in use.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot delete the scheduled task?  I am shocked the task even happens without the user being logged into.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment